# How do First Years know where their classes are?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

How do the first year students know where their classes are? I know in the books Harry and Ron get lost a few times, but how would they know where to head to in the first place?

Comment: How did you know where your high school classes were? Presumably you were told that history would be in "Mrs Smith's room", or in "Room 421". You would probably need help finding the room the first time, even though might be some logic to where numbered rooms are located. As time went on, you would have begun to find your way around.

Comment: With all the moving staircases in Hogwarts, @Blackwood, there's high likelihood of needing help finding rooms more than the first time! (as was evidenced in the books)

Comment: Agreed @FreeMan. The process of finding your way around is likely to take a lot longer at Hogwarts.

Comment: I don't think this question deserves that many downvotes..

Answer (score 9):

In Chapter Six of *Prisoner of Azkaban* we have the following passage:

> The Hall was starting to empty as people headed off toward their first lesson. Ron checked 
>   his course schedule.
>
> "We'd better go, look, Divination's at the top of North Tower. It'll take us ten minutes to get there...."

This tells us that the location of the class was written on the course schedule. Presumably that would be the case for the First Years as well.

In Chapter Twenty-Seven of *Order of the Phoenix* the location of the new Divination classroom was listed on the notice board, so that is also a possibility for how First Years could find out where their classes are:

> Parvati looked scornfully over her shoulder at him.
>
> “How d’you expect Firenze to climb that ladder? We’re
>   in classroom eleven now, it was on the notice board
>   yesterday.”